When using SignalR, should you check if the user is connected before sending a message?
What is the most efficient approach or the best strategy for sending a notification to specific users using SignalR? Should I verify the user’s connection status before sending the notification, or should I let SignalR handle this automatically? I need to send it to about 10k users, and checking if the user is online takes some overhead.
I have a current implementation where the pseudocode looks like this:
foreach (var user in Users)
{
    if (user.IsOnline)
        Clients.Group(user.ConnectionGroup).Notify("Hello");
}


Consider this - between checking the users status and sending the message, the user's status may change. There's no real way to check "if, in a short while, I attempt to send a message to this user, will they receive it?" Because their activity is independent from your code.
